# Counter code not counting properly

Tags: php, error-handling

Here is the code I use for counting on my site. The problem is that sometimes it does not count all the clicks.

```
<?php

//acquire file handle
$fd=fopen('counter.txt','c+b');
if (!$fd) die("");

//lock the file - we must do this BEFORE reading, as not to read an outdated value
if (!flock($fd,LOCK_EX)) die("");

//read and sanitize the counter value
$counter=fgets($fd,10);
if ($counter===false) die("");
if (!is_numeric($counter)) {
    flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
    die("");
}

//increase counter and reconvert to string
$counter++;
$counter="$counter";

//Write to file
if (!rewind($fd)) {
    flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
    die("");
}
$num=fwrite($fd,$counter);
if ($num!=strlen($counter)) {
    flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
    die("");
}

//Unlock the file and close file handle
flock($fd,LOCK_UN);
fclose($fd);

?>
```

I am not sure what to do now. Is there a better way of writing my code or should I use another technique?

Comment: There're too many `die("");` in your script, it's impossible to say which one exits script. Add some description in them. Finally, PHP is dynamically-typed language, this means that you don't need to cast things. I mean `$counter++; $counter = "$counter";`

Comment: this is simpler though, `file_put_contents('counter.txt');` , `$var = file_get_contents('counter.txt');`

Comment: @GeoPhoenix `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` don't support locking and won't handle collisions.

Comment: @MathieuImbert But I have tried it without none clicking on the button. I have tried loads of times.

Comment: @user1426486 As @PLB said, you have to debug your script, we cannot do it for you. Try to echo something when it dies: `die("1")`, `die("2")`, ... and see where it actually fails.

Comment: @MathieuImbert No errors. I have tried clicking in diffrent phases too.

Comment: @user1426486 So you have no errors, but it doesn't increment?

Comment: @MathieuImbert It increases the value, but to give you an example: When clicking 5 times, it only registers 3 clicks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14523/discussion-between-mathieu-imbert-and-user1426486)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per chat discussion with OP and after trying different approaches, we reached the conclusion that it would be more convenient to use a database to implement a click counter and handle concurrent access to the data.

```
mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
mysql_select_db(DATABASE); 
mysql_query('UPDATE tbl_click SET click = click + 1');
```